# Compare-Object in PowerShell does not work to show only the difference

Tags: powershell, object, compare, powershell-5.0

Tried below commands but fetches similar line entries in both variables as well

But my requirement is only to show difference in lines of both variables

Contents of value 1 are:

```
2273.32689.312
123.33.2312.1
5693.2.3.2.1
```

Contents of value2 are:

```
67556327.2.211.33
123.33.2312.1
55673.222.33.4
```

Output should be:

```
2273.32689.312
5693.2.3.2.1
67556327.2.211.33
55673.222.33.4
```

These are the commands I tried:

```
Compare-Object $value1 $value2 | select -ExpandProperty inputobject

Compare-Object $value1 $value2 -Property "$property" | Format-Table -AutoSize

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $value2 -DifferenceObject $value1 | select -expandproperty InputObject​
```

Comment: We need the examples your are using for `$value` and `$value2`. Show us what you get and what you expect to get. `Compare-Object` works for me as expected normally. Which version of PowerShell are you actually using?

Comment: Major 5 and minor 1 version

Comment: have edited question to show contents of value1 and value2

Comment: If I set `$value1 = ("2273.32689.312", "123.33.2312.1", "5693.2.3.2.1")` and similar for `$value2`, your first line returns perfectly good results. Is this how you have assigned the input arrays?

Comment: have assigned one line after the other.....line by line

Comment: Can you show us _how you assigned_ the contents of the variables? That would be the core of your issue. If it was a proper array then you should not be having a problem

Answer (score 0):

If your input objects contain single strings with multiple lines, you should split them by new lines to create arrays of strings: (if they're separated by spaces, use `-split ' '` instead)

```
$value1 = $value1 -split '\r\n'
$value2 = $value2 -split '\r\n'
Compare-Object $value1 $value2
```

Comment: it fetches values in both variable. but i need to fetch only differnces and similar values in both variables should not be listed in output

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me -

```
$value1 = @('2273.32689.312', '123.33.2312.1', '5693.2.3.2.1')
$value2 = @('67556327.2.211.33', '123.33.2312.1', '55673.222.33.4')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $value2 -DifferenceObject $value1 | select -expandproperty InputObject
```

I am getting the desired output as below -

```
2273.32689.312
5693.2.3.2.1
67556327.2.211.33
55673.222.33.4
```

The code which you have pasted has an extra character after `InputObject`. You might want to check that once in the line -

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $value2 -DifferenceObject $value1 | select -expandproperty InputObject​
```

​